# How to handle NULL parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the function `dbo.Split` in a `WHERE` clause while executing a stored procedure. I don't want to execute this function when the input Parameter is `NULL`.

E.g.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[HRMS_RPT_CategoryWiseSeniorityList]
   @fk_BranchRegion_ID bigint = null,  
   @pk_BranchType_ID nvarchar(100) = null  
AS        
BEGIN      
    Select distinct SR.fk_branchType_ID
    from HRMS_Employee_ServiceRecord SR (nolock)  
    Inner Join HRMS_Mst_Branch B  (nolock) On B.pk_Branch_ID = SR.fk_Branch_ID     
    Where         
        B.fk_BranchRegion_ID = IsNull(@fk_BranchRegion_ID,B.fk_BranchRegion_ID) --Region  Condition
        AND SR.fk_BranchType_ID in (SELECT * from dbo.Split( @pk_BranchType_ID,','))       
END
```

I use the following SQL to ignore the filter on `SR.fk_BranchType_ID` when `@pk_BranchType_ID` is `NULL`:

```
SR.fk_BranchType_ID = IsNull(@pk_BranchType_ID, SR.fk_BranchType_ID)
```

I want to do something similar for `@pk_BranchType_ID`.  If I use `ISNULL` like I did with `@pk_BranchType_ID`, I get no rows back. when it is `NULL`.

How can I get my stored procedure to ignore the filter on `SR.fk_BranchType_ID` when `@pk_BranchType_ID` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a filter when the input parameter is NULL, you can use a NULL-check in your `WHERE` clause, combined with an `OR` like so:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[HRMS_RPT_CategoryWiseSeniorityList]
@fk_BranchRegion_ID bigint = null,  
@pk_BranchType_ID nvarchar(100) = null  

AS        
BEGIN      
Select
    distinct SR.fk_branchType_ID
    FROM HRMS_Employee_ServiceRecord SR WITH(nolock)  
    INNER JOIN HRMS_Mst_Branch B  WITH(nolock) 
    ON B.pk_Branch_ID = SR.fk_Branch_ID
    WHERE B.fk_BranchRegion_ID = IsNull(@fk_BranchRegion_ID,B.fk_BranchRegion_ID) --Region Condition
    -- Remove filter on @pk_BranchType_ID when it is NULL
    AND (  @pk_BranchType_ID IS NULL
        OR SR.fk_BranchType_ID in (SELECT * from dbo.Split( @pk_BranchType_ID,',')) )
END
```

Comment: Sorry to say but this question states that i want to return rows even if parameter if NULL, please tell me if i can check parameter null or not in where for using dbo.Split

Comment: @user1280492 I just updated my answer based on your updated question.  This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the parameters to `null` like this:

```
@fk_BranchRegion_ID bigint is Null,
@pk_BranchType_ID nvarchar(100) is Null
```